# What N+ modem routers with VOIP exist?

Tags: router, wireless-networking, voip, modem

i'm looking to purchase an N+ wireless router with built in voip capabilities.

why n+, because i have some bad interference with my crappy (old) 802.11b Netgear Wtg624 router + nb1300 modem (yes, didn't i say old?) :) .. and i'm under the impression that N+ should hopefully break through my two walls much much better.

secondly, i have an apple air notebook, apple imac 24" (purchase quarter 3, 09), and apple iTV thingy and some iphones which i wish to all connect to wirelessly.

so .. could anyone help me please?

(i'm under the impression that some of those devices could only use G, not N or N+ .. but that's ok).

#### Update:

```
Are you looking for QOS handling to help ensure that your calls take priority
over other data?
```

Yep. QoS is a must (and most high end routers have this now, so I just assumed this

```
Are you looking for a router with a built-in Analogue Telphone Adapter(ATA)
so you can plug in your old handset?
```

Yep - this is the kicker :) I'm currently using a Sipura 3000 ATA device -> works 100% great (and has been for a few years) but I want an all in one device to get rid of some cables and power plugs.

Comment: What do you mean by "With VOIP capabilities"? At the most basic level, any router will be able to route the packets. Are you looking for QOS handling to help ensure that your calls take priority over other data?  Are you looking for a router with a built-in Analogue Telphone Adapter(ATA) so you can plug in your old handset? Are you looking for a router than can double as a SIP server?

Comment: SIP would be the more accurate description indeed. somethike this (just with Wireless N)? http://www.voiptalk.org/products/Surfinbird+IX68+ADSL+AIR+GW2+-+Clearance#tab_features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[FritzBox Fon WLAN 7270](http://www.voiptalk.org/products/FritzBox+Fon+WLAN+7270)** should meet your requirements.

[image]

- WLAN router with an integrated DSL modem (ADSL and ADSL2+) and 4 LAN ports
- DECT base station for connecting up to six cordless telephones
- Telephone system for Internet and landline telephony (ISDN or analog)
- Integrated answering machine
- USB port for network printers and memory
- Secure right from the factory thanks to activated WLAN encryption
- Supports the new WLAN-N standard
- Supports Annex A and Annex B lines with a single device

or the [**Vigor 2710VN ADSL Router**](http://www.voiptalk.org/products/Vigor+2710VN+ADSL+Router#tab_features)

[image]

- ADSL/ADSL2+ Router
- Compatible with ADSL, ADSL Max, ADSL2 &, ADSL2+
- Wireless - 802.11n (Draft 2.0) Wireless LAN
- Twin VoIP Phone Ports with POTS passthrough

Answer (score 1):

I have an airport extreme - one of the newer ones that not only has N, but also two radios, so it can do 2.4Ghgz and 5Ghz at the same time. It integrates nicely with the rest of my apple gear - several macbooks, a mini, an appletv.

I have a seperate VOIP gateway - an old Billion model that doesn't seem to be available any more - which has an ATA port and handles maintaining the SIP connection to my VOIP provider for me.

Comment: Thanks James. But i was looking for an all-in-one device. I've updated the opening thread with more info about what I ment by "with voip capabilities" (which you commented on correctly. On a side note, did u goto school in Geelong? Or you're brother?

Comment: Yes... I have a DSL modem, a router, the aiport extreme is just for wireless, and the VOIP device is just for VOIP. Not everyone's idea of an easy-to-maintain network :)

Nope, I grew up in Maryborough (the other one, in QLD)